# how to handle typescript error for type of string on query

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a query that does something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("h2, h3").forEach(header => {
    tmpNav.push({name: header.textContent || header.innerHTML, id: header.id, type: header.nodeName});
})
```

The content that comes through is typed against this interface:

```
interface IContent {
    name: string,
    id: string,
    type: "H3" | "H2"
}
```

I have a loop that goes through the `tmpNav` array and display the data, in which at some point I use the type from the `tmpNav` to insert a class based on it (jss):

```
className={classes[type]}
```

The issue I'm facing is when I create this array, the `type: header.nodeName` throws a type error because it is return a string that does match the type `type: "H3" | "H2"`

Adding it with `string` will cause my `classes[type]` to throw an error as it can't match that type.

I'm unsure how to go about this. I always know that the array will puch one of the type with `header.nodeName` as it's just a `querySelector` for `"h2, h3"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more suitable solution is using a conditional value check to narrow type of `header.nodeName`

```
if (header.nodeName === 'H3' || header.nodeName === 'H2') {
  tmpNav.push(...);
}
```